# Parse Autogenerated XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

There is a program where I work that will export the following student training schedule in XML. It's an unusual format but Is there a way to create an XSLT stylesheet to parse the data in table format? We have no way of changing the exported file. We are wanting to use the data to display for scheduling.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tablix2>
  <Details_Collection>
    <Details SCHED_START_DATE_TIME_DT2="26-Sep-2018" BS_CLASS_NM_ST2="18-11" 
    EQ_NAME_NM2="OFT 18" Textbox41="0500 - 0800" EVNT_NAME_NM_2="KPNM05" 
    Instructor2="Doe, John" Textbox40="Student, Jim" />
  </Details_Collection>
</Tablix2>
```

Comment: Right now there is not enough information to answer your question. But yes that seems to be the job of XSLT to parse XML to produce over kind of texts  (such as HTML which could be appropriate to display).

Comment: It's not such an unusual format, and it is easy to handle with XSLT. Especially so if each `Details` element has exactly the same attributes, in the same order.

Comment: What do you consider unusual about this format? It's completely standard XML and can be handled using completely standard XSLT. (Unless we know why you are finding the problem difficult, it's hard to give an answer.)

Comment: I admit, I am a total newbie to XSLT. I've seen other XML documents and they were formatted with individual open and closed tags so I thought this was 'unusual'. I've been reading several documents on XSLT but can't seem to figure out how to parse this type of list. Yes, the Details element is exactly the same for the entire document and it has more than just the short list I posted. What I'm wanting to do is create a table but change the header rows to something more identifiable for the 7 elements (START, CLASS, OFT NAME, TIME, EVENT, INSTRUCTOR, STUDENT) with data in the columns.